# Get specific column when Kendo Grid row is selected

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I'm quite new to Kendo UI and would appreciate if someone could give an advice.
I need to get a value of specific column when my grid row is selected. Till now I can get the values of all columns of selected row:

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
...
change:onChange,
columns: [{
            field: "Number",                
            title: 'Number',

        }, {
            field: "Title",
            title: "Title",               
        }]
});
```

onChange function:

```
function onChange(arg) {
        var selected = $.map(this.select(), function (item) {
            return $(item).text();
        });

        alert(selected);
    }
```

I need to take the selected value of `Number` column. Something like `$(item[name='Number']).text();`
I know I could parse the string but I guess there is another way.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be using the `dataItem` method of the Kendo UI Grid to retrieve the actual data item of the row you selected - [reference](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/web/grid#methods-dataItem). Then, you can retrieve the value you need by property name.

```
function onChange(e) {
  var selected = this.select()[0],
      item = this.dataItem(selected);

  alert(item.Number);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if you have multiple selection and want to collect first column of all selected row. use following code

```
      var allSelected = "";          
      var selectedRows = this.select();
        for (i = 0; i < selectedRows.length ; i++) {
            allSelected = allSelected + ", " + this.dataItem(selectedRows[i]).task_number;
        }
```